# I am using momentjs, and when using moment.startOf() the date/time comes back as end of the day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using momentjs, and when using  moment.startOf() the date/time comes back as end of the day.

```
  const startOf = momentIn.startOf(timePeriod);
  console.log('get startof ', startOf);
  return startOf;
};
const getEndOf = (momentIn, timePeriod) => {
  const endOf = momentIn.endOf(timePeriod);
  console.log('get endOf ', endOf);
  return endOf;
};

const nowMoment = moment();

const tempMomentStart = getStartOf(nowMoment, 'month');
const tempMomentEnd = getEndOf(nowMoment, 'month');
console.log('tempMomentStart', tempMomentStart.format('LLLL'));
console.log('tempMomentEnd', tempMomentEnd.format('LLLL'));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4dcn.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the same `moment` object. You could return a new moment object from individual functions like this.

```js
const getStartOf = (momentIn, timePeriod) => {
  const startOf = momentIn.startOf(timePeriod);
  return moment(startOf);
};
const getEndOf = (momentIn, timePeriod) => {
  const endOf = momentIn.endOf(timePeriod);
  return moment(endOf);
};

const nowMoment = moment();
const tempMomentStart = getStartOf(nowMoment, "month");
const tempMomentEnd = getEndOf(nowMoment, "month");
console.log("start of the month", tempMomentStart.format("LLLL"));
console.log("end of the month", tempMomentEnd.format("LLLL"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Or you could clone the moment objects inside the function using `clone` method

```js
const getStartOf = (momentIn, timePeriod) => {
  const startOf = momentIn.startOf(timePeriod).clone();
  return startOf;
};
const getEndOf = (momentIn, timePeriod) => {
  const endOf = momentIn.endOf(timePeriod).clone();
  return endOf;
};

const nowMoment = moment();
const tempMomentStart = getStartOf(nowMoment, "month");
const tempMomentEnd = getEndOf(nowMoment, "month");
console.log("start of the month", tempMomentStart.format("LLLL"));
console.log("end of the month", tempMomentEnd.format("LLLL"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how the library works, doesn't return a new item but mutates that item assigning it the new value.

You can read the [`moment().startOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) docs:

> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the start of a unit of time.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Because it changes the object itself ,so after getEndOf(nowMoment, 'month') all the objects has the same link - nowMoment. use copy() method may be

```
return startOf.copy()
```